# Two launcher entries for Skype after Skype-wrapper installation

Tags: unity, launcher, skype

I installed skype-wrapper because the Skype default icon looks awful with the rest of the unity bar (and I like the integration), and uninstalled the sni-qt package to remove the normal Skype icon.

Now when I launch Skype (through skype-wrapper) there are two icons for Skype in the launcher: the top one is the skype-wrapper icon, with the unity quicklists and the mail count, etc. The bottom one is just a normal Skype icon that's **not pinned** to the launcher.

[image: Two Skype launchers]

Did I do something wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: The same problem on 12.10. Sometimes it works normal, sometimes second Skype icon appear